# Java String parseFloat or double for x.xxxxxx numbers?

Tags: java, string, parsing, floating-point, type-conversion

I have numbers in String like:

```
"34.556231"
"43.385644"
"65.659388"
```

with six decimals after dot.

I want to parse them to Float or eventually Double.

How to convert these Strings to Float or Double?

When I use `Float.parseFloat("5.586905")` then the float value is equal `5.58691` so it looks like its parsing to only 5 decimal places and rounds it.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Indeed float has just 6/7 digits, and 5.58691 *has* 6 digits.

Answer (score 1):

`float` doesn't have enough precision to store the number you are giving it. Use `double` instead.

As the java specs say,

> As with the recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead
>   of double) if you need to save memory in large arrays of floating
>   point numbers

In other words, don't use `float` unless storage is a major concern. It is much less precise than `double` and will lead to ridiculous results like the one you just outlined.

Use `Double.parseDouble`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more numbers after decimal then you can use bigdecimal like this

```
String x="5.586905";
    BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal(x);
            double value=b.doubleValue()            ;
    System.out.println(value);
```

but as per your given number `Double.parseDouble()` is enough